# How to re-enable Analog Audio Output?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, headphones

I been using this forum for long time and never really needed to post my own questions since everytime I found useful and clever both questions and answers... Until now.

I tried every possible line code and workarounds to be able to use my laptop headphone jack.
It was working just fine with some minor bugs that got solved changing from one profile to another and back again, But a couple of days ago my laptop was plugged to a tv as usual and also plugged to external speakers, everything was working good until the tv suddenly restarted, then when the TV booted itself again the audio got routed to HDMI Digital Output and when I tried to get it back to the output anologue jack I see the option like this "Analogue Output (Headphones)(unplugged)" There and then is where my nightmare started I have like 3 nights sleeping just a couple of hours cause I cannot just forget about it. And anything I tried doesn´t work at all.

I tried with pavucontrol, pipewire, tried adding lines to the conf files, remove timidity, I checked the bios in case the soundboard was disabbled but no, I already check the alsamixer, I tried fresh install, I tried, Lubuntu, Kubuntu, and the issue now follows to any new fresh installation. I cannot share my entire terminal log of what lines I´ve been using cause I did multiples fresh installations In my attempt to make it working again. At some point I even losed entire sound, no speaker, no hdmi, no headphone jack. But cleaning pavucontrol conf files gave me back HDMI Digital Output, but nor internal speaker nor headphone jack is working It is like the computer cannot see it have it.

Im using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on a Dell Inc Vostro 3400 with Cirrus Logic CS8409 as audio device.
11th Gen Intel core i5 1135G7
Mesa intel Xe Graphics

--This is the output of

`lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel`

```
snd_hda_intel          61440  4
snd_intel_dspcfg       32768  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec         212992  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hda_core          147456  7 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_pcm               196608  12 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_sof_utils,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd                   143360  19 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

--This is the output of

`aplay -l`

```
** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices **
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

This is what alsamixer shows

[image: Alsa Mixer Prompt]

Can anyone help me? I know maybe Im not givin all detaills but it is because I don´t know what else to share. I´ll be happy to try everything you all will suggest in here as fast as possible

Comment: From your output, there is no evidence that the analog output is even detected. Have you tried seeing if the outputs are present in `hdajackretask` ?